# Using FFMPEG to add pillar bars

Tags: ffmpeg

I have transferred some film to video files from 16mm (native 4:3). The image looks great.

When I scanned them, I scanned to a native 16:9. As I overscanned them, I got the entire height of the frame, which is what I want. But it also got the soundtrack and perforation. But I want to go just to the frame line on the sides as well.

I can CROP the image down with FFMPEG to remove the information outside of the framing I want [-vf crop=1330:1080:00:00].
I know this will result in a non-standard aspect ratio.
This plays fine on a computer (vlc just adapts to the non-standard).

But for standardized delivery, I would love to keep the native 1920x1080 pixels, but just make everything outside of the centered 1330:1080 black.

Is there a way to specifically select where the pillar bars are?

I really want to re-encode the video as little as possible.

In that vein, does anyone have a better tool than -vf crop as well?

thank you very very much.

Answer (score 0):

Use [crop](https://ffmpeg.org/ffmpeg-filters.html#crop) then [pad](https://ffmpeg.org/ffmpeg-filters.html#pad):

```
ffmpeg -i input -vf "crop=1330:ih,pad=1920:ih:-1:-1" output
```

Comment: this is fantastic and just what I needed. the output looks great. Do you mind walking me through it just a tad? does ih=input height? If I need to recenter just a little bit would this still work?  ffmpeg -i input -vf "crop=1330:ih:281:0,pad=1920:ih:-1:-1"  what does the "-1" mean? thanks, I just want to learn exactly what I am doing.

Comment: @EwokBBQ Yes, for both crop and pad `ih` refers to the input height. crop auto-centers by default, but you can adjust as needed as in your example in your comment. The `-1` means "centered" as described in the [pad filter documentation](https://ffmpeg.org/ffmpeg-filters.html#pad) for the `x` & `y` offset parameters.